# How can I get Entity Framework to create and manage a database table relationship while preventing duplicates?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am trying to create a UserPreferences table that will contain every combination of 5 boolean values and will have Entity Framework automatically manage saving and retrieving combinations so that; if an incoming combination of boolean values does not exist in the UserPreferences table it would be created, and if an incoming combination already existed the existing values would be used rather than creating a duplicate entry with the same combination.

I'm aware that there are other ways to do this without relying on EF, but my question is: Is there a way to achieve this by letting Entity Framework create and manage the relationship?

Here is the relationship between the Customer class and the UserPreferences class:

```
public class Customer
{
    public string MyId { get; set; }
    public UserPreferences Preferences { get; set; }
}

public class UserPreferences
{
    public bool Bool1 { get; set; }
    public bool Bool2 { get; set; }
    public bool Bool3 { get; set; }
    public bool Bool4 { get; set; }
    public bool Bool5 { get; set; }
}
```

Note: I'm using .Net framework 4.5 and EF 6.

I've tried to solve this problem by configuring a composite primary key in my DbContext but that did not work, I also tried creating a composite primary key from the 5 bool values but that lead to extra rows on my Customer table:

```
public override void Up()
{
    CreateTable(
        "dbo.UserPreferences",
        c => new
            {
                Bool1 = c.Boolean(nullable: false),
                Bool2 = c.Boolean(nullable: false),
                Bool3 = c.Boolean(nullable: false),
                Bool4 = c.Boolean(nullable: false),
                Bool5 = c.Boolean(nullable: false),
            })
        .PrimaryKey(t => new { t.Bool1, t.Bool2, t.Bool3, t.Bool4, t.Bool5 });

    AddColumn("dbo.Customer", "UserPreferences_Bool1", c => c.Boolean());
    AddColumn("dbo.Customer", "UserPreferences_Bool2", c => c.Boolean());
    AddColumn("dbo.Customer", "UserPreferences_Bool3", c => c.Boolean());
    AddColumn("dbo.Customer", "UserPreferences_Bool4", c => c.Boolean());
    AddColumn("dbo.Customer", "UserPreferences_Bool5", c => c.Boolean());
    CreateIndex("dbo.Customer", new[] { "UserPreferences_Bool1", "UserPreferences_Bool2", "UserPreferences_Bool3", "UserPreferences_Bool4", "UserPreferences_Bool5" });
    AddForeignKey("dbo.Customer", new[] { "UserPreferences_Bool1", "UserPreferences_Bool2", "UserPreferences_Bool3", "UserPreferences_Bool4", "UserPreferences_Bool5" }, "dbo.UserPreferences", new[] { "Bool1", "Bool2", "Bool3", "Bool4", "Bool5" });
    DropColumn("dbo.Customer", "UserPreferences");
}
```

I'm not sure how to get Entity Framework to create and manage the relationship, perhaps there is an easier way to do this that I am overlooking? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't understand the point. Why do you want to store all combinations? Why not only the current user settings of a user?

Comment: I'm trying to avoid adding more columns to my Customer table so I've set up a separate table to hold the combinations. The separate table should store all the combinations so I don't create/store more data than I need to. If I have 1000 customers and they all set their preferences to 'true' for all 5 values I don't want to have 1000 duplicate rows.

Comment: You will need to code this logic yourself. When a user selects a combination of preferences, check if that combination exists, if it does assign it, if it doesn't create it.

Comment: @Colin Yeah, I ended up writing the logic to handle that part.

Answer (score 1):

You want to create a Foreign Key.

To do this in Entity framework, change your classes to look like this. The `UserPreferencesID` tells us EF that Customer is strongly linked to a single UserPreferences. Applying `virtual` to the `Preferences` property will allow EF to auto-fill the value of the property from the table based on the its ID.

```
public class Customer
{
    public string MyId { get; set; }
    public int UserPreferencesID { get; set; }
    public virtual UserPreferences Preferences { get; set; }
}

public class UserPreferences
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public bool Bool1 { get; set; }
    public bool Bool2 { get; set; }
    public bool Bool3 { get; set; }
    public bool Bool4 { get; set; }
    public bool Bool5 { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for responding, I tried that but adding the virtual keyword to the Preferences property does in fact create a foreign key, but the UserPreferencesID does not seem to automatically map the ID to a specific combination of boolean values. For example, I have 5 bools all set to true in my UserPrefs table with an ID of '1'. With a new UserPreference object when I call update on my dbcontext with the same combination (5 true values) rather than setting the ID to '1' it creates a duplicate entry with an ID of '2' and updates the UserPrefId column in the Customer table to '2' rathern than '1'.

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, I would not do it this way. It may sound like nitpicking, but this is not a normalized design. Who will guarantee that there will always be 5 booleans involved in user settings? What I would recommend is -

- To create a settings table as name-value pairs in which each user can have 5 records, currently. Maybe less or more in the future.
- To allow each user to have their own set of settings. It takes hardly any storage and it prevents these unnecessary searches for existing combinations of settings. If multiple users have the same settings, who cares?
- *If* you insist on doing it your way (maybe for reasons I don't know), I would pre-insert the 32 combinations, so you can always only do a lookup. Sooner or later all combinations will be there anyway.